# как поместить текст <figcaption> на <figure>

Tags: img

как поместить текст `<figcaption>` на `<figure>`?

```
<section>
        <figure>
            <figcaption id="design">We love design.<wbr>We provide the best design    advice for you.</figcaption>
            <img src="img/index.png">
        </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figure сделать `position:relative`
figcaption сделать `position:absolute`

```
.fig {
   position:relative
}

.figCapt {
   position:absolute; 
   left: 0; 
   top: 0; // получим текст слева сверху
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое Василий Барбашев